# How do I add a proper Doctrine Query builder and Join a table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying to build this SQL query into query builder but when adding a join, it breaks.  If I take out join it works but there are the item's in Join that id like to have access to.

I have tried different methods of using query builder, I have read the documentation and follow its instructions but its not working.

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM invoice i
      JOIN item it

WHERE  i.created_at >= '2019-03-26 08:00:00' and
i.created_at <= '2019-03-26 08:05:00' and i.status=2;
```

Here is my Query builder inside Symfony.

```
       /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em *
    $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

      /** @var EntityRepository $repository */
    $repository = $em->getRepository('GivingBundle:Invoice');

      /** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
     $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i');
    $qb->join('i.item', 'it')
         ->Where($qb->expr()->between('i.created_at', ':starts_at', ':ends_at'))->andWhere('i.status = 1')

        ->setParameter('starts_at',$startsAt,\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
        ->setParameter('ends_at', $endsAt,\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
```

However, I am getting an error (below)

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                                                                                          
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 66 near 'it WHERE (i.created_at': 
 Error: Class KCM\GivingBundle\Entity\Invoice has no association 
named item
```

What id like to do is select the Invoice table base along with the Item table so I can access both of its properties. I am trying to create a Symfony command that runs an SQL query, report results for items in status 2 and eventually adds it as a cronjob.

Comment: I think you have not to assign "i" alias for anywhere in doctrine.

Comment: I have, it runs if i omit the join, not sure where the query is going wrong.

Comment: Show your Invoice entity and Item entity. The problem is in annotations. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: Hi, i edit the file with my annotations

Answer (score 0):

Can you show code for associations in your entity? From your question it looks like, it should be something like

```
/** @Entity */
class Invoice
{
    // ...
    /**
     * This is the inverse side.
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Items", mappedBy="invoice")
     */
    private $items;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items= new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Items
{
    // ...
    /**
     * This is the owning side.
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice", inversedBy="items")
     * @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $invoice;
    // ...
}
```

More on associations at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 0):

I did not see a join in your QueryBuilder code, did you just forget it here or is that the error? I wrote a function below how it would work in my case, but something along these line should help you. I did not see a join condition in your plain sql so I assumed the column names are the same. If the Query is working but the error consists then take a look at the annotations in your entity, you probably need something like

- @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice")
- @ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", referencedColumnName="id")

in your entities. (Like already said by @Azhar Khattak)

```php
public function findInvoice($dateFrom, $dateTo)
    {
        $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('i')
            ->from(Invoice::class, 'i')
            ->join(Item::class, 'it', Join::WITH, 'i.created_at = it.created_at')
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->between('r.created_at', ':datefrom', ':dateto'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('i.status', 1))
            ->setParameters(['datefrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateto' => $dateTo])
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```